# What are the subspaces of $\mathbb{C}^n$?

Tags: complex-numbers, vector-spaces

It is fairly common knowledge that, for example, the only proper non-trivial vector subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^2$ are lines passing through the origin. So we have that if $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a vector space, then

$$W_\mathbb{R} = Span\{\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ \alpha \end{bmatrix}\} \hspace{1cm} \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$$

generalizes a line passing through the origin. This is fairly easily to understand. We can then assert that a similar case holds for $\mathbb{R}^3$ with planes passing through the origin and so on. How should one extend this to $\mathbb{C}^2$? In other words, what are the interesting subspaces of $\mathbb{C}^2$ (or even $\mathbb{C}^n$ for that matter)?

Do things carry over in a similar manner for $\mathbb{C}^2$? That is, can we say

$$W_\mathbb{C} = Span\{\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ \alpha \end{bmatrix}\} \hspace{1cm} \alpha \in \mathbb{C}$$

is a subspace of $\mathbb{C}^2$? Or is there perhaps something I am missing?

Comment: You can do linear algebra over an arbitrary field

Comment: (Lines through the origin in $\Bbb R^3$ are also subspaces.)

Comment: If you want to classify all subspaces of $\mathbb{C}^n$, this is far more complicated. Look up the Grassmannian.

Comment: When you say $\mathbb{C^{2}}$ do you mean over the complex field or the real field?. Those two are of different dimensions.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron over $\mathbb{C}$

Answer (score 1):

The analogy from real vector spaces carries over nicely to complex. Subspaces of $\mathbb C^2$ are precisely $\mathbb C^2$, the trivial subspace, and "complex lines," which are $1$-dimensional complex subspaces. So sure, $\mathrm{Span}\{\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ \alpha \end{bmatrix}\}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb C^2$ for any $\alpha \in \mathbb C$. However, the subspace spanned by $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ is missed here (same for $\mathbb R^2$).

Comment: Why is the span of $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ not a subspace? Or, rather, what do you mean by "missed?" You just mean that we're forgetting to mention it, I assume. We could cover that by also asserting that Span$\{\begin{bmatrix} \alpha \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \}$ generalizes a form of subspace for $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{C}^2$.